# Databricks - Try catch between cells

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks for my scala / spark execution and having few issues with Try / Catch method.

Databricks Notebook Cell 1:

```
try{
val b = "123a"
val c = print(b.toInt)
} catch {
case e:Exception=>
throw new Exception(e)
}

val b = "123a"
```

When I execute the above code, it throws the 'NumberFormatException' and it does not print b:123a

But, when I give both the statements in different blocks within notebook,

Block 1:

```
try{
val b = "123a"
val c = print(b.toInt)
} catch {
case e:Exception=>
throw new Exception(e)
}
```

Block 2:

```
val b = "123a"
```

When I execute the whole notebook, it still throws the exception in the Block 1 and executes the Block 2.

Is there a way stop executing other blocks when there is an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this code to stop the execution:

```
`dbutils.notebook.exit()`
```